# How to distribute python apps using PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, installation-package

I'm trying to package my code and distribute it using PyPI.
I want people to **install my package** and use it directly from the terminal as:

```
$pip install <package_name>
$<package_name>
```

What Package structure should I need to follow? How should I do this?

I've read this documentation. It doesn't have what I wanted.
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#a-simple-project

I'm expecting to package and distribute *my app using PyPI.* 
and execute directly from *Terminal*.

Comment: _It doesn't have what I wanted_ - what exactly are you missing? If it's about writing and packaging scripts, then here is a [tutorial](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) for that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [Command Line Scripts](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html). They allow you to add shell commands to your setup, so that you can later run them from the shell.

So if you want a script called `package_name`, first create a Python function that will be called when `package_name` is run from the shell. Say it's in `package_file.main`. Then you can add the following to your setup call:

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': ['package_name:package_file:main',],
}
```